# QDialog: How to enable being behind the parent (main window) on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

I use a `QDialog`. In the constructor, I set `setWindowFlags(Qt::Window)`. On Linux/KDE, the effect is that the dialog gets it's own window bar button and can go behind it's parent (the main window). That's what I want to have.

On Windows however, the dialog does not have an own window bar button, and it's always on top of the main window. Is it possible to achieve the same behavior on Windows as I have on Linux?

I played around with the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` window flag, but it had no effect.

Comment: That's something the OS/Window Manager is ultimately in control of. Not something you can dictate/force from an application - all you can do is provide *hints* as to your wishes and they then may or may not be respected. You can't always get what you want.

Comment: I'm totally aware of that. Thus, the question was if it's possible … ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pass your QDialog a NULL parent, then it is independent of your main window and can go behind the main window.

Then in your main window's closeEvent() function, call myDialog->close().  This will shut down the dialog when your main window exits.

Answer (score 0):

setup your dialog parent by sending its this pointer to your dialog constructor. for example in if your are showing a QFileDialog for staying top use

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open Image"), "/home/jana", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
```

instead of :

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL,
    tr("Open Image"), "/home/jana", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
```

Comment: ok , what is your qt version. because I tasted your problem in ubuntu 18.04 and windows 7 and by sending this pointer you should first finish the dialog and return to previews windows

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.11.2

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I found that if you use the StaysOnTopHint, the dialogs would stay on top of even other windows (not just the main application window). This did the trick for me. The code is in Python but should be easily translatable to C++. Here self.parent is the application main window.

```
        if staysOnTop:
            dialog.setParent(self.parent, Qt.Dialog | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        else:
            dialog.setParent(None, dialog.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Comment: This actually enables the dialog to be displayed behind the main window, but if the main window is closed, the dialog is not – and that's not the desired behavior …

Comment: It does close the dialog for me when I close main window for both the if and else cases. When the dialog is first instantiated, I do the following. So maybe try this: `self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.Dialog | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_QuitOnClose, False)`